# Dropdown menu on mobile doesn't hide on second click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to put this dropdown menu on my website:

```
*https://codepen.io/sean_codes/pen/WdzgdY*
```

My website is totally mobile-friendly.

When I click to open the menu on the phone, it opens normally, but when I click the second time, it doesn't close. It closes only when I click away.

How do I put that menu to close when I click the menu icon a second time?

Comment: Link to the menu: https://codepen.io/sean_codes/pen/WdzgdY

Comment: you might always want to reproduce part of the code you think is causing the error here than to add a link to an external site.

Comment: The code was very big and I didn't know what was causing the error

Answer (score 0):

It is best to avoid the usage of `hover` on mobile devices. You will first have to [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) if the browser supports it via `@media` and create some sort of fallback in case it does not.

Try using `input` html element and set the type to `checkbox` for your dropdown buttons and toggle your dropdown with `checked`.
[No need to use javascript for this.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=toggle+dropdown+css+checked&t=fpas&ia=web)